# Can't Display PointCloud2 in Rviz

Tags: rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to display a monochrome image/inverse depth map as a PointCloud2 in Rviz, but I'm getting garbage (basically random points) and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've verified that the image/K matrix is good and I'm setting the inverse depth to 1, so it's something to do with how I'm filling in the PointCloud2 message. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
void bufferVertices(const cv::Mat& img,
                    const Eigen::MatrixXfR& idepth,
                    const Eigen::Matrix3f& Kinv,
                    uint32_t point_step,
                    std::vector<uint8_t>* buffer) {
  Eigen::Vector3f uv1;
  Eigen::Vector3f xyz;
  uint32_t offset = 0;
  for (int ii = 0; ii < img.rows; ii++) {
    for (int jj = 0; jj < img.cols; jj++) {
      uv1(0) = jj;
      uv1(1) = ii;
      uv1(2) = 1.0;

      xyz = Kinv * uv1/idepth(ii, jj);
      memcpy(&((*buffer)[offset + 0]), &(xyz(0)), sizeof(float));
      memcpy(&((*buffer)[offset + 4]), &(xyz(1)), sizeof(float));
      memcpy(&((*buffer)[offset + 8]), &(xyz(2)), sizeof(float));

      float g = static_cast<float>(img.at<uint8_t>(ii, jj));
      memcpy(&((*buffer)[offset + 12]), &g, sizeof(float));

      // uint8_t g = img.at<uint8_t>(ii, jj);
      // int32_t rgb = (g << 16) | (g << 8) | g;
      // memcpy(&((*buffer)[offset + 12]), &rgb, sizeof(int32_t));

      offset += point_step;
    }
  }

  return;
}

void publishPointCloud(const std::string& frame_id,
                       const cv::Mat& img,
                       const Eigen::MatrixXfR& idepth,
                       const Eigen::Matrix3f& Kinv,
                       ros::Publisher* pub) {
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Ptr msg(new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2());
  msg->header = std_msgs::Header();
  msg->header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  msg->header.frame_id = frame_id;

  msg->height = img.rows;
  msg->width = img.cols;

  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Modifier mod(*msg);
  mod.setPointCloud2Fields(4, "x", 1, sensor_msgs::PointField::FLOAT32,
                           "y", 1, sensor_msgs::PointField::FLOAT32,
                           "z", 1, sensor_msgs::PointField::FLOAT32,
                           "intensities", 1, sensor_msgs::PointField::FLOAT32);

  msg->is_bigendian = false;
  msg->point_step = 4*sizeof(float);

  msg->row_step = msg->point_step * msg->width;
  msg->is_dense = true;

  msg->data.resize(msg->row_step * msg->height);
  bufferVertices(img, idepth, Kinv, msg->point_step, &msg->data);

  pub->publish(msg);

  return;
}
```

EDIT:
I've tried writing the PointCloud2 message to a PCD file using pcl_ros and can visualize it just fine in pcl_viewer. In addition, the cloud appeared in Rviz for maybe a single frame and then disappeared. Maybe this is a tf issue? I thought I was publishing the requisite transforms (world -> camera_world ->keyframe). This is my main loop:

```
  /* Main loop. */
  tf::Transform camworld_to_world_tf;
  tf::Quaternion camworld_to_world_q(0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
  camworld_to_world_tf.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  camworld_to_world_tf.setRotation(camworld_to_world_q);

  std::string frame_id;
  ros::Rate loop_rate(30);
  while (ros::ok()) {
    /* Do optimization step. */

    /* Publish tf from camera_world to world. */
    tf_camworld_to_world_pub.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(
      camworld_to_world_tf, ros::Time::now(), "world", "camera_world"));

    /* Publish tf from camera to camera_world. */
    frame_id = "keyframe" + std::to_string(kf.id);
    Eigen::Vector3f eig_trans = cam_to_world.translation();
    Eigen::Quaternionf eig_q = cam_to_world.quaternion();

    tf::Transform cam_to_camworld_tf;
    cam_to_camworld_tf.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(eig_trans[0],
                                             eig_trans[1],
                                             eig_trans[2]));
    tf::Quaternion q(eig_q.x(), eig_q.y(), eig_q.z(), eig_q.w());  // This is scaled!
    // cam_to_camworld_tf.setRotation(q);
    // cam_to_camworld_tf.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    cam_to_camworld_tf.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1));
    tf_cam_to_camworld_pub.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(
                         cam_to_camworld_tf, ros::Time::now(),
                         "camera_world", frame_id));

    /* Publish point cloud. */
    publishPointCloud(frame_id,
                      img,
                      mu_idepth,
                      Kinv,
                      &keyframe_pub);

    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203144/can%27t-display-pointcloud2-in-rviz/) by [wng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2471/wng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just tried this on another machine and it worked fine. Seems like the issue was that my machine was using an older version of OpenGL (2.1 GLSL 1.2). On a machine with OpenGL 4.4 GLSL 4.4, it works fine.

---

Originally posted by [wng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2471/wng/) with karma: 78 on 2015-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1